# Installed everpad, but lenses doesn't work

Tags: lenses, everpad

I installed everpad through the nvbn-rm ppa (https://launchpad.net/~nvbn-rm/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) apparently everything works well except the unity integration with the everpad-lenses, it doesn't show off when I open the unity dash.

Here what happens when I try to launch it through the terminal:

```
 $ everpad-lens 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/everpad-lens", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('everpad==2.5dev', 'console_scripts', 'everpad-lens')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/specific/unity/lens.py", line 3, in <module>
    from singlet.lens import SingleScopeLens, ListViewCategory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/singlet/lens/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from singlet.lens.base import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/singlet/lens/base.py", line 140, in <module>
    class SingleScopeLens(Lens):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/singlet/lens/base.py", line 57, in __new__
    if isinstance(a, Unity.Scope):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 320, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Unity' object has no attribute 'Scope'
```

- I already restarted the system
- Running ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bits

Comment: I would consider this a bug so you should file a bugreport against everpad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a bug report already exists see: [Everpad lens 13.10+](https://bugs.launchpad.net/singlet/+bug/1248050)

A work around does exist and appears to work well. See: [Unity Scope Everpad](https://github.com/SlavikZ/unity-scope-everpad)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the work around here, and provide the link for reference.